# React-Minisearch: Argument of type '...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly never[]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data from firestore using the firebase sdk and useQuery from Tanstack-Query, but when I try to index it to react-minisearch it throws a type error (the error is down below).

I am completely new to tsc and I'm trying to migrate my js react app into tsc.

The useQuery hook that fetches data from getPublicData and indexes it to react-minisearch

```
  const { data: setsData } = useQuery<ILibraryCard[]>({
    queryKey: ["publicSets"],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const data: ILibraryCard[] = await getPublicSets();
      await addAllAsync(data);
      return data;
    },
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
  });
```

*data* in addAllSync throws error

*Argument of type 'IUserDisplayInfo[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly never[]'.

Type 'IUserDisplayInfo' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)*

My getPublicData hook:

```
export const getPublicSets = async (): Promise<ILibraryCard[]> => {
  const docsQuery = query(
    collection(firestore, "studySets"),
    where("isPublic", "==", true)
  );
  const arr: ILibraryCard[] = [];
  const docsSnap = await getDocs(docsQuery);
  docsSnap.forEach((doc) => {
    const data = doc.data();
    arr.push({
      title: data.head.title,
      description: data.head.description,
      id: doc.id,
      creator: data.creator,
    });
  });
  return arr;
};
```

Interface:

```
export interface ILibraryCard {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  id: string;
  creator: string;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

If this issue is missing something critical related to the issue, please let me know so that I can provide any additional information since this is my very first issue that I've made.

I've tried changing types but the addAllAsync doesn't seem to accept anything else than "*readonly never[]"*